# Where to find the signature of a function in Julia?

Tags: julia

Just starting to use Julia, but I can't figure out how do you actually find the function signature in any of the docs...

For example, let's say I want to see what parameters the `gradient` function of the Flux package takes.
How can I find that? If I go to flux docs it's mostly english docs and not function signatures. Similar for julia docs.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Open a repl and type `?gradient` `?` puts you into help mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this function is lacking proper documentation and the standard approaches described in other answers (`?` for the help REPL or methods) will not be very useful.

What I normally do in such cases is to type something line:

```
@edit gradient(1,2)
```

This brings me to function definition (actually I can suspect the first parameter is a function  but running `methods` did not indicate anything.

This will open the editor and you will see something like this:

```
function gradient(f, args...)
  y, back = pullback(f, args...)
  return back(sensitivity(y))
end
```

So at this stage you know what your function is doing. If not perhaps you can search for `pullback` typing `?pullback`. When you do that you discover that there is no documentation for this neither but it is a part of `Zygote`.

However, typing into Google `Zygote.pullback` will forward you to the documentation you need: https://fluxml.ai/Zygote.jl/latest/adjoints/

So this is kind of hackish. Most of Julia libraries are nicely documented but if not I always start the job with `@edit` macro.

Comment: Thanks, I was kind of hoping that since it uses types, the signature would be easier to find than in a dynamically typed language.

Comment: if you run `methods` function then it is enough in REPL to write the method number and press Ctrl-Q to go to the definition of the selected method. Regarding the signature - as I have commented in my answer - essentially value of any custom type can be made callable as a functor so restricting the signature would problematic here.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `methods` function to get a list of signatures of all methods of a given function. For example:

```
julia> methods(sin)
# 13 methods for generic function "sin":
[1] sin(x::BigFloat) in Base.MPFR at mpfr.jl:727
[2] sin(::Missing) in Base.Math at math.jl:1197
[3] sin(a::Complex{Float16}) in Base.Math at math.jl:1145
[4] sin(a::Float16) in Base.Math at math.jl:1144
[5] sin(z::Complex{T}) where T in Base at complex.jl:804
[6] sin(x::T) where T<:Union{Float32, Float64} in Base.Math at special/trig.jl:29
[7] sin(x::Real) in Base.Math at special/trig.jl:53
[8] sin(A::LinearAlgebra.Hermitian{var"#s827",S} where S<:(AbstractArray{var"#s828",2} where var"#s828"<:var"#s827") where var"#s827"<:Complex) in LinearAlgebra at /home/bkamins/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LinearAlgebra/src/symmetric.jl:922
[9] sin(A::Union{LinearAlgebra.Hermitian{var"#s828",S}, LinearAlgebra.Symmetric{var"#s828",S}} where S where var"#s828"<:Real) in LinearAlgebra at /home/bkamins/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LinearAlgebra/src/symmetric.jl:918
[10] sin(D::LinearAlgebra.Diagonal) in LinearAlgebra at /home/bkamins/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LinearAlgebra/src/diagonal.jl:576
[11] sin(A::AbstractArray{var"#s828",2} where var"#s828"<:Real) in LinearAlgebra at /home/bkamins/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LinearAlgebra/src/dense.jl:836
[12] sin(A::AbstractArray{var"#s828",2} where var"#s828"<:Complex) in LinearAlgebra at /home/bkamins/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LinearAlgebra/src/dense.jl:843
[13] sin(J::LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling) in LinearAlgebra at /home/bkamins/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/LinearAlgebra/src/uniformscaling.jl:139
```

Comment: Here is what I get: 
`# 1 method for generic function "gradient":
[1] gradient(f, args...) `
But it doesn't say anything about types of f or args. Is there just a convention that f is a function?

Comment: In this you can pass any values as `f` and `args...` and you will not get `MethodError` (which does not mean you will not get an error later, as `f` should be callable). Note though that not only `<:Function` are callable. Also types are callable (calling their constructors) and functors (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects-1) are callable.